# Which are the required file in Splitview ZIP on github to make the plugin work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, github, ipad

I am trying to implement a split view, as we can see on jquery mobile demo:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/

The plugin :
http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/

Inside the archive, they are many (unneeded) files, and the author also include an old jquery mobile version.

I already have the latest version of jquery mobile, and i'm trying to add juste the files I need to make it work.

I have readen the readme files, the author show a basic html page to make it work, but don't provide any explaination about the installation.

I'm pretty sure i don't need everything.

Comment: I wonder why the readme is called readme?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is opening the index.html in the zip file and check what files are included in header, which can make splitview run correctly. You need include all those files too. Another thing is you need to notice the different versions of jquery mobile and jquery (both js and css files ). For my experience, it seemly cannot work fine with latest versions of jquery mobile and jquery. What I did is open each js and css file and copy them to my library.

Hope this could be helpful for you.

Comment: I Tried this way, but i didn't figure it out.

Comment: It works fine for me. Another way is using the original splitview file, and make changes on that file. English is not my language, is this clear enough to you ?

Answer (score 0):

Splitview makes changes INSIDE JQM (adds a class .forgotwhatitwas to events, so they can be disabled later on from inside splitview.js). Unless you port these tweaks over to the current version of JQM, the splitview script will not get you anywhere.

Comment: You might be right, I tried as Gavin says, to check with my current version of jQuery mobile, each files that could be usefull for splitview. (unsuccessfully)

I agree to use only the files in the split view archive file so i can make it work, but the probleme remains the same, there is many files & folder (jquery ui, jquery documentation, css, js) that I don't need to make a split view.

Even if I want to downgrade to their Jquery Mobile version, I wouldn't be able to make it work.

I tried to contact the author of this plugin, but still have no answer.

Comment: I have been working with splitview for half a year, so I know it changes JQM and isn't compatible with the current JQM version. I think my multiview plugin is the closest compatible you will get, if you want to run splitscreen in JQM). However I will only have time to update it sometimes this week, the current version on [Github](https://github.com/frequent/multiview) is already a few months old and still on JQM 1.0.1. Plus I fixed a lot of stuff for a current project, which I need to port to Github. Check there next week if you want to give it a try.